# How to listen a result from a command using tail?

Tags: 18.04, tail

I would like to perform this command:

`tail -f | tac myfile.txt`

`tac` reverts the order of the lines, the command works fine, except for the "listen" part.

When the file is updated, the `tail` command doesn't update the console.

Is it possible to perform this?

Comment: When you do `tail -f | tac myfile.txt`, the `tail -f` command is tailing standard input, while `tac` is (separately) reversing the `myfile.txt` - nothing actually gets piped from one to the other afaik. OTOH if you do `tail -f myfile.txt | tac`, the `tac` is going to hang waiting for `tail -f` to finish (because it can't seek to the end of standard input).

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for your answer, I did solve my issue adding `watch`'s command.

Comment: I was wondering if `watch` might provide a solution - please add an answer showing how you solved it

Comment: This was my solution @steeldriver `watch -n 0.5 "tail -n -50 /filepath/filename.txt | tac"`, it's not exactly what I was looking for, but solves the issue for my personal use.